# Javascript: calling function onsubmit does not intercept parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a snake game in Vanilla JS in which there is a possibility of changing levels. Each level is represented by a different maze that is being produced by a function:

```
function createMaze(selected) {
  for (let y = 0; y < selected.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < selected[y].length; x++) {
      if (selected[y][x] === 1) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(x*10, y*10, 10, 10);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The level changes thanks to a form:

```
<form id="levelSelect">
  <select id="levels">
    <option value="gridLevel1">One</option>
    <option value="gridLevel2">Two</option>
    <option value="gridLevel3">Three</option>
    <option value="gridLevel4">Four</option>
    <option value="gridLevel5">Five</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

That is defined here:

```
const levelSelection = document.querySelector("#levelSelect");
const levelDropdown = document.querySelector("#levels");
```

And then being called in event listener:

```
levelSelection.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  selected = levelDropdown.options[levelDropdown.selectedIndex].value;
  createMaze(selected);
  console.log(selected);
});
```

As at the very beginning the createMaze function does not have a specific parameter due to no selection being performed, I included a clause:

```
if (!selected) selected = gridLevel1;
```

And as the game starts, the createMaze(selected) function is being called.

However, even if in the event listener I am able to log out the value that is the name of the level (that is also the name of the array representing each level) when I'm calling the function createMaze(selected) it does not seem to work. If I log the selected in creatMaze, it prints out only the name of the array instead of the array itself.

Comment: I wouldnt use a form if you are actually not trying to redirect / post

Comment: from what i understand is that you are passing a `string value` to your `createMaze function` but its expecting a `Array`

Comment: @fayeed, indeeed - any tips on how to be pass this parameter?

Comment: @llievredemars check the answer below he sums up the solution pretty much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `selected` is a string, such as `"gridLevel1"` but you want it to be a variable `gridLevel1`. That can easily be done by looking it up in the window object:

```
 window["gridLevel1"] // gridLevel1
```

Or in your general case:

```
createMaze(window[selected]);
```

But although this works you should consider putting the levels into an object:

```
const levels = {
  gridLevel1: [ /*..*/ ],
  //...
 };
```

So you can do:

```
createMaze(levels[selected])
```